# Как замедлить скорость прокрутки в слайдере?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пробую написать декоративный слайдер, который будет переключать список маленьких картинок в заголовке секции. Количество картинок может менятся.

```js
function moveSlide() {

  /*тут я определяю массив со слайдами*/
  var containerNum = $('.slide-1 .slider .slide');

  /*тут я определяю длину массива со слайдами*/
  var countVar = containerNum.length;

  /*тут я определяю какой-же из слайдов активный*/
  var activeVar = containerNum.closest('.active');

  /*запускаю бесконечный цыкл, который считает слайды по очереди*/
  while (true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < countVar; i++) {
      containerNum.eq(i).addClass("active");

      /*класс добавлен элементу И*/

      containerNum.eq(i).removeClass("active");

      /*класс удален у И-того элемента*/
    }
    /*Наша песня хороша начинай сначала.*/
    if (i == 5) {
      i = 0;
    }
```

```css
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrap slide-1">
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/1.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/2.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/3.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/4.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/5.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Цикл летает со скоростью света и вешает браузер.
Что с этим делать - не знаю.
Вот пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/6f14s0tw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно Вас понял:

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var i = 0;

function slide() {
  for (var j = 0; j < slider.children.length; j++) {
    slider.children[j].className = 'slide';
  }
  slider.children[i].classList = 'slide active';
  i < slider.children.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;
}
setInterval(slide, 2000);
```

```css
.slide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/1.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/2.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/3.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/4.png">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slider/5.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ухты, спасибо! Про функции className и classList не знал)

Answer (score 0):

1. Не используйте `alert();`. Существует `console.log();`.
2. Нужно запускать функцию, которая добавляет класс `active` через `setInterval();`.

Comment: Спасибо! В данном случае alert(); выполнял полезную функцию, он останавливал выполнение сценария чтобы предотвратить зависание браузера.